# Django extra fields on many-to-many relationships admin add in reverse order

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

The default admin interface for many to many relationships with extra fields is as shown in the following image
[image]

Is it possible to define that the items in this list are displayed in reverse order, so that the new field stays always on the top first line?

Answer (score 0):

in django/contrib/admin/options.py

line number about 265:
find this method:

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Get a form Field for a ManyToManyField.
    """
    # If it uses an intermediary model that isn't auto created, don't show
    # a field in admin.
    if not db_field.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
        return None
    db = kwargs.get('using')

    if db_field.name in self.raw_id_fields:
        kwargs['widget'] = widgets.ManyToManyRawIdWidget(db_field.rel,
                                self.admin_site, using=db)
        kwargs['help_text'] = ''
    elif db_field.name in (list(self.filter_vertical) + list(self.filter_horizontal)):
        kwargs['widget'] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(db_field.verbose_name, (db_field.name in self.filter_vertical))

    if 'queryset' not in kwargs:
        queryset = self.get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
        if queryset is not None:
            kwargs['queryset'] = queryset

    return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
```

try to manipulate/reorder returned value or try to look at the **kwargs values

Comment: Thanks Ohad, i tried looking at what you suggested but with no luck. I think i have found where is should make my change, it is in "inlines.js". I made another question wince it is javascript related. Here is the link in case you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039535/django-javascript-reorder-formset